Concatenate two geoshape charts in Altair / Vega-Lite with independent axis?
I am trying to plot two separate geoshape charts and concatenate them together. Below is a MWE of what I am trying to do:
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
import geopandas as gpd

source = data.us_10m

source = gpd.read_file(source.url).set_crs(epsg=4326)

r1 = alt.Chart(source).mark_geoshape().transform_filter(alt.datum.id == '49047')
r2 = alt.Chart(source).mark_geoshape().transform_filter(alt.datum.id == '20123')

r1 | r2

Plotting them separately works great; Altair plots the shapes and zooms to their extents automatically.
R1:

R2:

However, when I try to concatenate them, they share axis limits, and each chart's view expands large enough to show both even if only one is displayed.
Concatenated Plot:

My expectation is that I get the R1 and R2 images above next to each other without the additional zooming. I tried to set the axis to resolve independently, but it did not change the output.
(r1 | r2).resolve_axis(x='independent', y='independent')

Answers for how to do this in Vega-Lite, without the Altair abstraction, would also be useful.

Generally to change the scale you would use resolve_scale rather than resolve_axis (the latter just changing the visibility of the axis line). However, that doesn't seem to work either. I'm not sure why, maybe there needs to be an option to resolve lon/lat rather than x/y. Could you open an issue in the VL repo with this?

Hi Joel, thanks for the response. I've created an issue in the vega-lite repository here

It appears that this is a bug in Vega-Lite and I've submitted an issue in the repository.
In the meantime, I have identified a workaround that has minimal/no side effects. Vega-Lite will not scale the charts to cover each other's extent if they use different projections. We can therefore slightly change the projection of each chart and it will behave as desired.
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
import geopandas as gpd

source = data.us_10m

source = gpd.read_file(source.url).set_crs(epsg=4326)

r1 = alt.Chart(source).mark_geoshape(
    ).transform_filter(alt.datum.id == '49047'
    ).project('equalEarth')

r2 = alt.Chart(source).mark_geoshape(
    ).transform_filter(alt.datum.id == '20123'
    ).project('equalEarth', precision=.707)

r1 | r2


